# Частично отсутствует перевод в очереди проверок "Предлагаемые правки"

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

В проверке правки закрытого вопроса одна фраза на английском ([ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/874871) на проверку):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Оригинал:

> The editor has indicated that this is a significant edit that improves and/or resolves problems with the closed question. Approving this edit may send it to the Reopen votes queue.

Предложил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16745) (уже второй):

> Редактор отметил, что это значительная правка, которая улучшает и/или решает причину закрытия вопроса. При принятии этой правки вопрос может быть отправлен в очередь Голосов за переоткрытие.

Comment: Подредактировал и утвердил. Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.8.24.43599.

Comment: "улучшает причину" звучит странно

Comment: @andreymal перефразировал.